# PYTHON - .replace function

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a DF similar to the below:

| Name | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | 66l additional text |
| John | 55i additional text |
| Mary | 88l additional text |

What I want to do is anywhere "l" occurs in the first string of the "Text" column, then replace it with "P"

**Current code**

```
DF['Text'] = DF['Text'].replace({"l", "P", 1})
```

**Desired Outcome**

| Name | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | 66P additional text |
| John | 55i additional text |
| Mary | 88P additional text |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace) with regex to identify the first word of the string.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>>
>>> df
                  Text
0  66l additional text
1  55i additional text
2  88l additional text
>>>
>>>
>>> df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r"^\w+\b", lambda x: x.group(0).replace("l", "P"), regex=True)
>>> df
                  Text
0  66P additional text
1  55i additional text
2  88P additional text
```

Comment: @rftr I believe it will work fine now (after the edit), although I believe the `l` to replace occurs only once in the first word, so the solution can be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming the `l` only occurs once (as is shown in your sample dataframe) you can use

```py
df['Text'].str.replace(r'^(\S*)l', r'\1P', regex=True)
# => 0    66P additional text
#    1    55i additional text
#    2    88P additional text
#    Name: Text, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dVZI4z/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S*)` - Group 1: zero or more whitespaces
- `l` - an `l` char (letter).

The replacement is `\1P`, i.e. the Group 1 value + `P` letter.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples only, this could be easily done by using `str[range]` functionality of Python pandas, with your shown samples of DataFrame please try following code.

```
import pandas as pd
##Create your df here....
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str[:2] + 'P ' + df['Text'].str[4:]
```

***Explanation:***

- `df['Text'].str[:2]`: Taking(printing) from 1st position of column `Text` to till 3rd position(it starts from `0`).
- `+ 'P ' +`: Adding/concatenating `P` to it as per OP's requirement in question here.
- `df['Text'].str[4:]`: Taking(printing) from 5th position of column `Text` to till end of column's value here and saving this whole `df['Text'].str[:2] + 'P ' + df['Text'].str[4:]` code's output into `Text` column itself of DataFrame.